# Multiple writable mappings for field exception on entityManager.clear() with Eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, orm, eclipselink

We are customizing an external JEE project (no base source code modifications, only configuration and inheritance). I'm encountering following exception:

```java
Exception [EclipseLink-48] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.v20151217-774c696): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorExce
ption
Exception Description: Multiple writable mappings exist for the field [MY_TABLE.ERROR_CODE].  Only one may be defined
 as writable, all others must be specified read-only.
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[errorCodeString-->MY_TABLE.ERROR_CODE]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(my.package.somwhere.DerivedClass --> [DatabaseTable(MY_TABLE)])

Runtime Exceptions:
---------------------------------------------------------

        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:593)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TransactionScopedEntityManager.createEntityManager(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:187)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TransactionScopedEntityManager.getEntityManager(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:91)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.clear(AbstractEntityManager.java:331)
        at my.code.some.function.somwhere...
```

Issue might be related to the fact, that indeed there are multiple mappings for `ERROR_CODE` colum. This is the original mapping:

```java
@Entity
@Table("name="MY_TABLE")
public class BaseClass implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Column(name="TRJ_ERROR_CODE")
    private Integer errorCode;
}
```

Which was overriden, with column type changed from `NUMBER` to `VARCHAR2`:

```java
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("X")
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "errorCode", column = @Column(name = "TRJ_ERROR_CODE", updatable = false, insertable = false))
})
public class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {
   ...
   @Column(name = "TRJ_ERROR_CODE", length = 200)
   private String errorCodeString;
}
```

```xml
<!--ORM.XML-->
    <entity class="my.package.somwhere.DerivedClass">
        <attributes>
            <transient name="errorCode"/>
        </attributes>
    </entity>
```

The issue occurs only on `enitityManager.clear()` call. Persisting entity works without any issues. Debugging an eclipselink SessionCustomizer reveals only one mapping - where does the second come from? How can I disable the original one? I wasn't able to find any examples of this issue with a `org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping`, not a `OneToMany`, `OneToOne` etc. relation.

Entity manager is injected using this snippet:

```java
@PersistenceContext(unitName = SomeConstants.PERSISTANCE_JTA_UNIT_CODE, type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Comment: It seems to appear on 'clear' as you haven't done anything else with the context, so it wasn't deployed yet - clear just happens to be the first call that forces your JBoss wrapper to fetch/build the underlying wrapped EntityManager context. If persist is happening before/after this call - that is a strange issue then with your container, as this is a persistence unit deployment error which should invalidate the app entirely. Turning on logging for eclipseLink should show you the classes and mappings as it processes them during deployment and set deploy-on-startup property to get it upfront

Comment: As for your type change: this isn't a type change, as the underlying "ERROR_CODE" column still exists and maps to the Integer errorCode property. Try removing the AttributeOverride: it is for specifying a different DB column and so likely getting confused with "ERROR_CODE" on BaseClass.errorCode and "ERROR_CODE" on DerivedClass.errorCode and any other subclass mappings. The error specifically states though that it is the errorCodeString property mapping to "ERROR_CODE", which isn't what you put on the errorCodeString mapping in the problem description.

Comment: @Chris Sorry, there was a typo - there's no 'ERROR_CODE' column, just 'TRJ_ERROR_CODE'. Integer in Base class, and String in Derived. On DB there's only VARCHAR TRJ_ERROR_CODE (modified from NUMBER). What's strange, is that the EM complains only in a single message-driven bean, I've added EM injection code to description.

In stateless session beans, and some other message driven ones any operation on EM works without issues, complete with persisting  'Derived' objects with errorCodeStr provided.

Comment: If you turn on logging and bump up the level, EclipseLink will log something for each mapping it processes, as it processes them. This might indicate why this context isn't deployed on your clear() call, and why it discovers multiple mappings that it didn't find elsewhere. I would suspect a class loading issue with this area of the code.